# How to fix Route not defined error in view, with Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am getting an errorexception on my view(ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 296:). This is my view code:

```
<a href="{{route('home')}}/downloads/<?php echo $d_n;?>/<?php echo basename($file['name']);?>" target="_blank"><?php echo basename($file['name']);?></a>
```

For a while it worked, but not don't and I don't know why and how to fix it. I guess I must write something in route.php, but not sure what.....

Comment: why are you using route('home') and again appending other variables after that. All these can be combined in a single route. Can you show your route file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
Route::get('home', ['as' => 'home', function () {
       return 'home';
    }
]);
```

Comment: A little bit explanation would make your answer even more useful

Comment: In view you route function refferences to name of the route, which defined in routes in 'as' syntax.